# Record a Video in Isaac Sim

Tags: render, simulation, nvidia, nvidia-isaac

In Isaac Sim it is possible to export individual frames via the [Animation Recorder](https://docs.omniverse.nvidia.com/extensions/latest/ext_animation-recorder.html) or [Movie Capture](https://omniverse-content-production.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/Assets/Isaac/Documentation/Isaac-Sim-Docs_2022.2.1/extensions/latest/ext_movie-capture.html). There are several forum posts concerning the question if entire videos can be recorded (see [here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/how-to-record-the-animation-of-the-robot-to-create-a-render-with-movie-capture/251393), [here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/how-to-capture-a-movie-in-a-python-standalone-application/202832) and [here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/how-to-record-video-in-movie-capture-extension/273912).). However, no satisfying answer has been found yet. Therefore, I'm trying to open this discussion on Stack Overflow. The specific question is whether the "intended workflow" is to export the individual frames and combine them into a video, or whether there are already existing solutions to create a high-resolution, rendered video of the simulation?

Thank you very much!